# Using HTML, can you define your own elements?

Tags: html

I've been pondering this question for quite some time. Ever since I saw that this piece of code:

```
document.createElement('myelement');
```

resulted in this:

[image: user defined element example]

I've just been wondering if it's a flaw or if you can really make these up. I know that I can see the made-up element right there but how would I use it? How do I give it semantic meaning in HTML?

Comment: With the right `DTD`, the world's your `<element>` oyster :)

Comment: Good call @Russ Cam - Reminds me of the way Microsoft Office creates `HTML` documents. We make our own rules!

Comment: And to think there are people who still think XML and XHTML aren't worthwhile.

Comment: I'm okay with this as long as you don't try creating a new `<blink>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've just been wondering if it's a flaw

It's not a flaw exactly. It's a very useful feature of browsers that they permit the construction of elements and attributes that are not valid to any existing specification. It means that when new additions are made to those specifications, all the existing browsers will automatically support them.

> How do I give it semantic meaning

Just get everyone else to agree as to what it means. If you invent a [`<nsfw>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-nsfw-element/) element and I agree as to what that element means, then it has acquired semantic meaning. The more people who agree with the meaning, the more useful it becomes. The classical way to get everyone to agree is to write a specification, publish it, and advocate it.

This is what [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/) did. While as a group of browser manufacturers they were in control of what new elements *did* in their browsers, their only right to define the semantics was to convince everybody that their definitions were the best ones. For that reason, it's perfectly reasonable for people like Jeremy Keith to argue that they [haven't always got it right](http://24ways.org/2009/incite-a-riot).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if it's valid html (truthfully I don't think it is), but it does work.

It's purpose would be as a div, so instead of making a div with id "this section" you could make  and then format it with CSS, it's probably better to just stick with divs though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it will not be strict [XHTḾL](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) anymore. No modern browser will know what to do with your elements really, so it's probably causing more pain than good.

Still, IE allowed you to do this a [long time ago](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301515.aspx), but I suppose that in the meantime one has realized that this is not really what you want. See also the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags).

If you are really obsessed with the thought about custom semantical markup, you should look into XML and XSLT - you can define XML markup with your custom elements and then transform this to valid (X)HTML afterwards using XSLT transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript Question is how you get old versions of Internet Explorer to recognize HTML5 syntax such as:

```
< aside >
< article >
< nav >
...etc
```

In which case: you would use

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.createElement('header');
        document.createElement('nav');
        document.createElement('section');
        document.createElement('article');
        document.createElement('aside');
        document.createElement('footer');
        document.createElement('hgroup');
    </script>

    <style type=text/css">
        header
        ,nav
        ,section
        ,article
        ,aside
        ,footer
        ,hgroup 
        { 
        display: block;
        }
</style>

<![endif]-->
```

You could use it in others ways, however with javascript disabled it definately wouldn't function.